# нерабочий change_presence | discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Проблема проста:
при попытке использования change_presence в конце on_event метода выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 46, in on_ready
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming("YouTube: Alan Bolton"))
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Вот код on_event:

```
@bot.event # работает всегда
async def on_ready():
  while True:
    rand = randint(0, 4)
    if rand == 0:
      await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("Отдыхает на Дубаях")) # Задаём игровой статус 
      sleep(15)
    elif rand == 1:
      await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("Глючит как всегда"))
      sleep(15)
    elif rand == 2:
      await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("Думает как уничтожить человечество"))
      sleep(15)
    elif rand == 3:
      await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("yeet"))
      sleep(15)
    elif rand == 4:
      await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming("YouTube: Alan Bolton"))
      sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать это:

```
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="My Stream", url="stream url"))
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: теперь мне временно заблокировали доступ к API xD

Comment: Вышел из бана и протестировал. Вроде работает, но возникла проблема: бот вырубается в Дискорде, в консоли пусто, а в логах психует:

```

Answer (score 0):

```
2021-12-16 11:15:22,662:DEBUG:discord.gateway: Sending "{"op":3,"d":{"game":{"type":0,"name":"yeet","timestamps":{}},"afk":false,"since":0.0,"status":"online"}}" to change status
2021-12-16 11:15:22,662:DEBUG:discord.client: Dispatching event socket_raw_send
2021-12-16 11:15:31,587:WARNING:discord.gateway: Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 150 seconds.
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 173, in <module>
    bot.run(token) # Обращаемся к словарю .env с ключом token, для получения токена
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 713, in run
    loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1859, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 44, in on_ready
    sleep(15)
```

Comment: После применения варианта Stalono

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, дело в `while True:`

Т.к. какой смысл от бесконечного цикла?
Если ты его уберешь, то бот будет менять статус каждый раз, когда ты запускаешь бота.

Comment: мне надо, чтобы статус менялся постоянно, а не по запуску бота